# How do I avoid misusing tags?

Tags: support, tags, faq-proposed

How do I know if I'm misusing tags, how can I avoid it?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Markdown link sample: `Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)`

Comment: How often, really, is this question/problem posed?  That is to say, how often does an average user on Stack Overflow come to the conclusion that they're misusing tags, and wants to ask Meta about it?

Comment: @Makoto It's intended more as a reference post to direct people (especially new users) to when there is clear tag misuse (which happens continuously in certain tags, like [android-studio] and [visual-studio]; for awhile, *virtually all* of the questions in the [openvpn] tag were off-topic).

Comment: My concern is how useful a post like this would ultimately be.  What's this post worth outside of two minutes of editing the most egregious forms of tag misuse?

Comment: @Makoto I don't think that editing is a substitute for helping new users learn to use the site properly - that's one of the reasons I typically point out something like "How to Ask" when I downvote/VTC. At best, editing is a band-aid after the fact.

Comment: @EJoshuaS The help center and FAQ *already* cover all of this.  If there's something specific missing on the topic, just add it to the existing topics.  Additionally, there's no need for a topic to be an FAQ for you to link to it in comments.  FAQs are for Frequently Asked Questions, and this is, by no means, a frequently asked question.

Comment: @Servy At a minimum, the way that certain tags are being handled isn't working very well. For example, the [website] tag specifically says not to use it (which is actually evidence that it should be burninated, but that's a different issue), but it still regularly attracts questions (mostly from new users). Also, I don't think that the help center article is all *that* helpful and it's not like I can go edit it. (I suppose I could do a feature request for it, but I truthfully don't have much confidence in that process given that even high-scoring posts are routinely completely ignored).

Comment: @EJoshuaS So given that there are *already* lots of information on meta describing everything that you're covering, and the problems are still happening, then we know that you creating duplicates isn't going to fix the problem.  Again, if you want to have something to link to, there are already lots of other existing (better) questions you can link to.

Comment: @Servy Yes, the information does exist elsewhere (nothing in this post is new information), but there's not really a post that's suitable as a reference post, so I think that this question still serves a purpose. I seriously doubt that we're going to be able to convince new users to read 5 different articles to learn to tag properly, so IMHO it's worth having a concise guide to avoiding tag abuse that new users are more likely to actually read.

Comment: @Servy Plus, writing "don't use the [android-studio] tag for general computing programming questions" in comments over and over gets *really* old after awhile ;)

Comment: @EJoshuaS The help center is suitable as a reference post, as is the exiting FAQ on how to tag your question.  Both of which are better at telling a user how to properly tag their question than this is.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Creating this post isn't going to result in you posting that comment less.  The people mistagging the questions aren't going to see this post.

Comment: (late, but) it's about as visible as other FAQ posts. Most people don't read them, but linking to it elsewhere increases the chances of it being seen my people - not just people who need hte info, but also people who moderate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As context, you may want to read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) prior to reading this.

The primary purpose of tags is to connect experts with questions that they will be able to answer. In other words, when a specific tag is used, experts that follow the tag will read that question. If tags are misused, it's much less likely that someone able to answer the question, or someone looking for an answer to the question, will see it.

With that said, the first step is to make sure that your question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site in the first place. For example, the fact that a [vpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vpn) tag exists isn't evidence that you can ask general questions about configuring and using VPNs on this site. Please also see [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) of what kinds of questions you should *avoid* asking.

Questions that are excessively opinion-based, don't contain enough information to diagnose the problem, aren't directly related to writing computer programs, or otherwise don't conform to the rules in the help center may be [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Secondly, make sure that you've identified all of the relevant tags. This will help people who are likely to know the answer to your question find it more easily, and it can also give additional context for your question. For example, if you're asking a question about a GUI framework, please be sure to tag which one you're using.

Third, please read the usage guidelines carefully. As you type, the system will show descriptions of what each tag is for:
[image]

Please read this carefully and completely before using a tag; it will tell you when you should use the tag and may include examples of when *not* to use it. For example, in the image the [documentation] tag description tells you that

> For posts related to help pages (documentation for the site itself), use [help-center] instead.

The description for [documentation-proposals] advises you that

> For questions about proposed changes, use [proposed-changes] instead.

This is especially important for heavily-misused tags. A few examples of tags that are misused regularly:

- Tags related to IDEs like Android Studio, Visual Studio, and Eclipse. In general, you should only use these if your question is actually directly related to the tool itself; you should *not* use these tags for general programming questions, even if you happen to be using those tools to write your code.
- Similar-sounding tags. For example, Java and JavaScript are decidedly *not* related languages, so the only time you should use both tags is if your question is genuinely related to both.
- Tags where only a limited subset of questions are on-topic. For example, the [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) tag should only be used for programming-related questions, *not* for general SEO questions.
- Tags that are being phased out (["burninated"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)). Some topics may no longer be considered within the scope of Stack Overflow. Some tags are simply ambiguous or not particularly meaningful. See also: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate).

So, in summary:

- Make sure that your question is a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please consult [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of topics you may ask about here for more information.
- Make sure that you've identified all of the relevant tags for your question so that people who are likely to know the answer to your question can find it more easily.
- Be sure to read the entire tag description carefully. In particular, the tag usage guidance will sometimes describe circumstances where you *shouldn't* use that tag.

Comment: Unless you mean for this to be focused on tag usage for Meta, you should prefer to draw examples (and screenshots) from the main site.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure that tagging on Meta's all that different than tagging on the main site, so I think that the example will be adequate for illustration.

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  For starters, Meta tagging *requires* that you include either [meta-tag:discussion], [meta-tag:bug], or [meta-tag:feature-request], which *is not* available or mandated on the main site at all.

Comment: @Makoto That's true, but otherwise it's not really all that different. I don't think that that difference is relevant to this post.