# What can be done to help people lessen mistagging unity questions as "UnityScript"

Tags: discussion, tags

Unity used to have its own scripting language called [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript), for some time now this language has been discontinued and deprecated, making C# the only native out of the box supported language (outside of plugins/dll's which can use other languages).

However a lot of questions ([near daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript+unity3d)) still get tagged with both [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)and [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) while really they are questions about [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)[c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and have absolutely nothing to do with UnityScript.

The confusion likely comes from people thinking something along the lines of "this is a script in Unity, thus it is a UnityScript" (bad naming on Unity's side)

Right now the tag info mentions this at the end of the excerpt (emphasis mine)

> A deprecated scripting language used by the Unity game engine in versions prior to 2018.2. It is often mistakenly referred to as Javascript, but does not follow the ecmascript standards. Do not use this tag to describe Unity scripts which are written in C#: **UnityScript is a separate language and should be used only on questions using that language.**

But we all know how well people read those, especially all the way through to the end.

What can be done to better inform users about the usage of this tag? Is there a system that can display a warning when certain tags are used in combination to let the user know they have likely mistagged it?

Of course anyone with editing rights can just remove the tag, but that creates an unnecessary bump and work if it can be prevented in some way.

Comment: There isn't really much to do. The approach I took on [tag:android-studio] (while I was still actively editing) was that I always left a comment - that can prevent OP from mistagging in the future, as well as impact anyone who reads it, and recruit more editors to help with the never-ending flow of mistagging. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags is also useful to link to

Comment: It seems the only way to educate such users is to *tell* them, one at a time ("can you explain why you did not read the tag description?" "-- uh what is a tag description"). Until now, I don't think any amount of education, popups, or warnings has worked.

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree. I find mistagging to not really be a problem with repetition - most users will get the hint if the tag gets edited or if a comment is left with "I don't think tag X is appropriate". OK, sometimes they don't but in my experience most of the time the user understands the issue. But there is just *so many* users who do a one time mistake. So one by one education hardly helps. Tag descriptions also hardly help - I see people misusing them all the time. Sometimes the tag says "THIS IS ABOUT X DO NOT USE FOR Y" other times literally "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Comment: I suppose doing that would help (atleast some) people from repeating the mistake, one issue with it though is that a lot of questions in the Unity tag are one time askers to begin with

Comment: I monitor the JavaScript tag. There are quite a lot of questions mistagged as Java and JavaScript or even just Java that turn up. I don't completely blame the askers - the confusing name scheme is definitely at fault. But still, if you're a student with homework you could *at least* know which language your code is in. At any rate, very rarely do I see a repeat mistagging. Sometimes the question askers actually did know better but tag autocomplete was why they had the incorrect tag. So, yes - I don't see individual education as something that would solve a lot of problems.